# AMQP (RabbitMQ) and passing data in work-flow situations to other consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, amqp

I'm working with RabbitMQ 3.7, and I'm finding that my microservice architecture is starting to feel tangled and coupled.

[image]

I'm finding that I'm *publishing messages from within my consumer's `received` event to other queues*. **This feels wrong.** But I'm not sure what the alternative is, since I benefit from the efficiency in passing the data from the consumer directly to the next queue/task.

*Note that the above is just an example, and the service I'm running are similar, and fairly work-flow dependent (although they can be ran independently!)*

Questions:

1. How is data normally passed from process to process (or consumer to publisher) in situations where the micro-services are fairly dependent on each other. Not that they can't be ran individually, but that they work best in a work-flow scenario?
2. If the solution involves *not* publishing new messages from within the `received` event of a consumer, then what is the proper way to get the data to that microservice/process?

Comment: for me it feels wrong that you process messages from broker and doing a business logic in the same thread. By this, you block processing of another messages. Normally, you should have a separate thread/loop to receive messages and pass them via event bus or another mechanic to your internal business task processor/create task worker directly in new thread to process new incoming task(depends on your needs and app. model). A result could be picked up by sending thread loop or directly from task processing thread/worker

Comment: @Reishin Yea, that's what I'm currently doing. I have a scheduler that determines when the website needs to be scraped, passes the broker the URL and some AUTH parameters, and the receiver/consumer actually performs the scraping. (And then as mentioned above, publishes the scraped data from within the consumer to another broker). I like what you're saying - do you know of any articles or tutorials that can help me see a concrete example of what you're mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

I find that chaining workflows across queues can create more complex workflows than desired, where on the other hand, creating simpler consumer applications can make for more maintainable code.

Do you gain or lose any scalability or simplicity in your code by splitting the first two steps? Without more detailed info to consider, I probably would not split up the first two parts of the functionality. I don't see anything wrong with directly storing the scraping results.

I like your isolated consumer for sending email, though you might consider making a generic email sending consumer that any of your applications could use and have the message format contain the proper mail parts and have the consumer construct the mail and deliver it.

I don't think there's a "right" answer to your architecture here other than to think about finding the right balance of simplicity/complexity, scalability, and maintainability.

Comment: I too am looking for a solution.  My consumer should do an ack and publish atomically and hence looking for a way: consumer -> ack -> message into the another queue.

Answer (score 0):

> microservice architecture is starting to feel tangled and coupled.

Usually when you work with microservices, what you are trying to decouple is not only the business logic, but its implementation of the components/steps.
You turn your business logic application, into a distributed application but the logical dependencies and flow of the application do not necessarily change, that's why sometimes it can feel tangled.

What you usually decouple with microservices are :

- **Developer teams**
- **Business Logic/Responsibilities** : decouple responsibilities of business logic components, eg a services that handles incoming data from sensors, another for managing users etc..
- **Service Lifetime Cycle** (testing/releases/versioning)
- **Hardware dependencies** (eg. a service needing GPU in server, or extra ram etc)
- **Software dependencies**, like 3rd party packages/dll/frameworks
- **Runtime Isolation** : separate at process level (containers) the one service from the other. Avoid a crash from one component bringing everything down and protect the system from an unsecured/vulnerable services exposing everything.
- **Monitoring** : examine per-service log messages, activity, health data, exceptions.
- **Manage** : per-service scaling/restarting/updating

### Job Scheduling

More specifically for your examples i would recommend looking into a **Job Scheduling** solution instead for a message broker.

Two good frameworks are :

1. [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io)
2. [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net)

I mostly use HangFire before it doesn't need a separate dedicated server.

#### Sample

[This is a good sample of HangFire](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/tree/master/103_JobScheduling) from [Phoesion Glow](https://glow.phoesion.com), a framework for developing, deploying and managing **dotnet** microservices.
In this sample there is an `Email Service` that receives email requests as **Jobs** *(Consumer)* and a `SampleService1` that creates/add the jobs *(Producer)*.

The sample also demonstrates **inter-service** communication by sending the request to `Email Service` and a **R**emote **P**rocedure **C**all *(RPC)* and the `Email Service` is responsible to add the job and respond with success. *(This is not necessary, as the `SampleService1` could use HangFire directly to submit the job)*

*Disclosure : I am a developers of Phoesion Glow*